# TemplateBinding to the same Property

Tags: wpf, templatebinding

Would anyone explain what does this TemplateBinding bind to?

```
// excerpt of a Style that applies to an ItemsControl
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <local:PiePanel Values="{TemplateBinding local:PiePanel.Values}"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

PiePanel defined a DependencyProperty

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValuesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Values", typeof(ObservableCollection<double>), typeof(PiePanel), ...
```

AFAIK, The TemplateBinding translates to

```
<local:PiePanel Values={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=local:PiePanel.Values}" />
```

So the Values binds to the Parent's Values property which is defined in the Child?  Is my interpretation correct?  The Values property is not defined for the Parent (in this case the TargetType of the Style).

Comment: The `{TemplateBinding}` inside the `ItemsPanelTemplate` resolves to the `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Does that mean Values is bound to ItemsControl.Values?  But Values is defined in the class that inherits from ItemsControl, not in ItemsControl.

Comment: No, it's an `Attached` DP, which is different from a regular DP. Pretty much like `Grid.Row="Something"`. the Values DP in the PiePanel instance is bound to the value of the attached property `PiePanel.Values` associated to the `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Would you explain why is this done?  Or should it be done?  In the usage example, Values is not defined.

Comment: Im not sure why somebody would want that. The `ItemsControl` already has an `ItemsSource` property which can be used to set its `Items` from a binding source. using an attached property to do the same makes no sense to me. Unless its some kind of "double ItemsControl" which shows 2 different lists of different things.

Comment: This is found inside the ChartControls project in Prism.

Comment: Charts are complex controls that actually show an X axis, a Y axis, and the values.

Comment: @HighCore: If you post your answer as an answer rather than a comment, the question can be marked as answered?